# ubuntu-core-20-amd64.img on ProxMox 7

Tags: ubuntu, proxmox

I followed this guide;
https://blog.viktorpetersson.com/2019/10/03/ubuntu-core-on-proxmox.html

Transposing 18 for 20 but when I start the VM it just goes into a boot loop saying No OS found.
I get the same when I try to use the .img file and when I convert it to an .iso file and create the VM that way

I cannot seem to get Ubuntu Core to work on ProxMox 7

Comment: Use the correct URL. Go actually [look](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/20/stable/current/) to see what the filenames changed.

Comment: As mentioned above, I have used the URL above as a guide and transposed the 18 for 20 using the correct image